# Integrating Active Directory with Plone 4

Tags: active-directory, plone

How do you integrate Active Directory with Plone 4 on Ubuntu?  I have searched the Internet up and down and cannot get this to work!!

All I know is that all you have to do is add "plone.app.ldap" in your buildout.cfg file and that will install the add-ons.  However, every time I do this I get an error message.  I have installed python-ldap 2.3.11 from the Ubuntu repos but yet I still get an error when I run bin/buildout.

When I run bin/buildount it starts Getting distribution for 'python-ldap>=2.0.6'.  I don't understand why does it have to do that when I already have python-ldap installed and tested successfully!

I have Python 2.6.

Here is the message I get when I execute bin/buildout:

```
Getting distribution for 'python-ldap>=2.0.6'.
extra_compile_args: -g
extra_objects: 
include_dirs: /opt/openldap-RE24/include /usr/include/sasl
library_dirs: /opt/openldap-RE24/lib
libs: ldap_r lber sasl2 ssl crypto
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:9:0:
Modules/errors.h:8:18: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occured when trying to install python-ldap 2.4.3. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'python-ldap>=2.0.6'.
Error: Couldn't install: python-ldap 2.4.3
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
plone.app.ldap = 1.2.6

#Required by:
#Products.PloneLDAP 1.1
Products.LDAPMultiPlugins = 1.14

#Required by:
#Products.PloneLDAP 1.1
Products.LDAPUserFolder = 2.20

#Required by:
#plone.app.ldap 1.2.6
Products.PloneLDAP = 1.1

#Required by:
#Products.LDAPUserFolder 2.20
dataflake.ldapconnection = 1.2

*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please post the error message when asking a question!

Comment: I am afraid you will need some experience with Python if you are going to attempt a Plone/ActiveDirectory integration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that you've actually included the error, it turns out this is a whole different issue.  You can't build python-ldap without having the [LDAP development package](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/installing.html#prerequisites) avialable.  On any debian based system, such as ubuntu, you can use the excellent deb package metadata to do this for you.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-ldap
```

Comment: Virtualenv?  What's that?  Distribute?  Sorry, I'm a complete noob when it comes to Python.  I have included in the original post the error messages I get when I run bin/buildout.

Comment: Updated now that you've actually provided details.